# Issue in Lightning component with locker service

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am facing an issue when I included static resource library of jquery expression builder. My component is running on bundle version 39 but when I increase the version it stops loading jquery expression builder query. Please suggest how can I proceed with increased version of bundle.

Below is the code:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="CPGCategoryLogic" >
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',$Resource.JQuery244 + '/jquery-2.2.4.min.js',$Resource.QueryBuilderStandaloneMin + '/query-builder.standalone.min.js',$Resource.CPGCommonScript,$Resource.BootStrap + '/bootstrap.min.js')}" styles="{!join(',',$Resource.QueryBuildCSS + '/query-builder.default.min.css',$Resource.BootCSS + '/bootstrap.min.css',$Resource.common_css)}"  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initPage}" />  
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_small" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <div id="builder"></div>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-set">Set Rules</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-get">Get Rules</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="btn-reset">Reset</button>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is to check your browser's JavaScript console and see what error messages are output; you may be able to work-around the problem if it is clear what it is. Then try the latest version of the library - looks like [2.4.5](http://querybuilder.js.org/) - add that as a static resource and reference it.

But many libraries are not a good fit and will not work - see [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html).

Comment: There are no error messages. And we tried with version 2.4.5 but still it is not working

Comment: @Jill_sfdc That's a bit unusual. You can use your browser's dev tools to set breakpoints in the library and your JavaScript code to investigate further.